# Can't boot FreeBSD after installation

Tags: boot, freebsd, windows, dual-boot, bsd

I've installed FreeBSD on my system along with Windows 7 using this [tutorial](http://edubuddy.net/freebsd/dual-boot-windows-7-and-freebsd-9-0/). When I turn on my PC the screen says something like this:

```
F1  FreeBSD
F2  Win
F3  ?

F6 PXE
Boot: F1 _
```

Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> successfully boots my Windows 7. But when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> nothing happens, it just types out a `#` on the screen.

Why is this happening? And how can I boot FreeBSD?

Comment: Windows 7 will not allow changes to the boot sector and that is what is preventing you from booting FreeBSD. I never run Windows so that's all I can tell you about this.

Comment: Did you do anything differently than the tutorial (I see that at least the order of the OSes is different)? Are both OSes on 1 drive or are they on separate drives? My computer now is multibooting Win, FreeBSD & Linux (although I'm using GRUB2 bootloader & not "boot0cfg" -- not familiar with that one)

Comment: See if this is the problem: http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=33684

Comment: Are you sure the `#` is not FreeBSD's root prompt?

Comment: @transistor1 I followed the tutorial. I installed Windows first and then FreeBSD. And yeah, my problem is similar to the one in that link.

Comment: @tripleee I don't think so, because, pressing more buttons adds more `#` on the screen.

Comment: I would try dropping into a rescue console from the FreeBSD disk and try the last 3 commands according to kpa's post in the link I sent you. He says that the # indicates you're missing a 2nd stage bootloader. But you need to make sure you install it on the correct partition. What I meant by "the order of the OSes" is that your partitions were reversed from the tutorial. In your case BSD is in partition 1 and Win is in Partition 2. In tutorial, Win is in partition 1 and BSD is in partition 4.

Comment: Also make sure you're using primary partitions, and not logical partitions (assuming your disk is using an MBR partition table)

Comment: Ignore the comment about Windows 7 not allowing changes to the boot sector. The boot sector has been changed, or you wouldn't be seeing that F-key menu.